# Meteor: how to get current directory while testing packages

Tags: meteor, tinytest

I have test configuration files and such that I'd like to run tests on, but the other ways I've used to get the current directory (e.g. process.cwd()) fail with 'process not defined' errors.

The Assets set only allows text and binary read (not access to full path name).

Anyone have a good solution to this issue?

Thanks,

ssteinerX

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find absolute base path of the project directory (after Meteor 0.6.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378809/find-absolute-base-path-of-the-project-directory-after-meteor-0-6-5)

Comment: `process` is only available on the server. Are you running it on the client?