# Get the full path of a file inside a Meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am writing a compiler for Meteor. One problem I'm facing is I need to include the compiler itself in the package (written in Node.js as `compiler.js`), and use "node" command to execute it:

`node compiler.js`

Including `compiler.js` as source to `Package.registerBuildPlugin()` doesn't work, because first, the file is huge (5.6MB) which significantly slows down the entire execution cycle of Meteor, second, it's a pure node.js script and has a few compatibility errors when included in Meteor apps.

My plan is to use child process to execute the node command above (similar to how it's done in this [TypeScript compiler for Meteor](https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-compiler/blob/master/plugin/compile-tsc.js#L184). So here comes my problem: is there a way to get the path of compiler.js, so that I can spawn a node executable to execute the compiler script?

( The [`Npm.require('fs')` trick](https://gist.github.com/awatson1978/4625493#gistcomment-1544872) doesn't seem to work, neither does [`process.env.PWD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20319903/707362), because they both give a wrong path).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!